# TCP socket buffer is getting cluttered

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

So, I'm sure this question has been asked before as it is a common issue with TCP. However, I searched around and could not find a solid answer.

I am sending data through a tcp socket, however if I send data too quickly my buffer will grow larger and I can't unserialize my buffer into a Packet.

So, here is my question, what is a good solution for checking if the stream has finished sending one packet, before it can send over another packet?

Comment: Two-way communication. Make a server send an acknowledgement when it receives the whole message and make clie to wait for the ack before sending another message.

Comment: I considered this method, however the problem is that uses unnessecary bandwidth.

Comment: TCP cannot transfer packets, only byte streams.  You need a protocol on top - design one or use an existing one.

Comment: That's not the point, I wrote a packet class which is serialized to byes then sent out and deserialized on the client.... The point is: the buffer gets cluttered when stuff is sent too quickly, I'm probably just going to go with the method to verify that's its able to accept data